# How can I query the a single record partitioned by a field in SQL?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have an SQL Server table that has data in the format:

```
Timestamp     Name     Price
2018-01-02    Name1    0.10
2018-01-03    Name1    0.20
2018-01-04    Name1    0.30
2018-01-02    Name2    0.40
2018-01-03    Name2    0.50
2018-01-04    Name2    0.60
2018-01-02    Name3    0.70
2018-01-03    Name3    0.80
2018-01-05    Name3    0.90
```

And I am trying to write a select query that returns the **most recent** (by `Timestamp`) for each unique `Name`. So for the data example above, the query *should* return:

```
Timestamp     Name     Price
2018-01-04    Name1    0.30
2018-01-04    Name2    0.60
2018-01-05    Name3    0.90
```

I would have suspected the query to be something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM mytable ORDER BY Timestamp DESC GROUP BY Name
```

however, this has a syntax error.

Does anyone know if a query like this is possible? **How can I get the most recent rows (`Timestamp`) for each unique `Name`?**

I am using Microsoft Azure SQL, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql, an ORDER BY always comes after the GROUP BY
Also, a `SELECT *` with a GROUP BY won't work on most databases.

But in MS SQL Server, you can combine TOP WITH TIES & ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Timestamp DESC)
```

If the result also needs to be sorted by the field(s) used in the PARTITION, then just put in a sub-query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
   FROM mytable
   ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Timestamp DESC)
) q
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a CTE to find the timestamp/name pairs, and then join back to the base table to project the price column:

```
WITH CandidateRows ([Timestamp],[Name])
AS
(
  Select MAX([Timestamp]), [Name] From TestTable GROUP BY [Name]
)
SELECT T1.[Timestamp], T1.[Name], T2.[Price] 
  FROM CandidateRows T1 JOIN TestTable T2 
  ON T1.[Timestamp] = T2.[Timestamp] AND T1.[Name] = T2.[Name]  
  ORDER BY T1.[Name] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `subquery` here :

```
select * 
from table t
where timestamp  = (select max(timestamp) from table where name = t.name);
```

Note : Be careful while you have same date in same name